# Why is Quectel BG96 stuck at trying to register the CS service?

Tags: iot, at-command, lte, m2m, quectel

I'm trying to get a BG96 up on to the Verizon network to do some MQTT communication.

The Quectel docs say to follow the TCP/IP AT command state machine before doing the MQTT commands. Makes sense to me.

I have an activated SIM card with an M2M data plan for this device, but it never seems to get past the second step, registering for CS service. It gives status of 2, "Not registered, but MT is currently trying to attach or searching an operator to register to." I checked the antenna and moved to a location closer to windows, but no luck.

```
at

OK

at+cpin?

+CPIN: READY

OK

at+creg?

+CREG: 0,2
OK
```

The same status is returned for the PS services, FWIW, but that's not surprising I think because the Quectel BG96 AT docs say you must register CS service first.

Any idea why a BG96 would be stuck at status 2 for `at+creg?`?

Comment: I couldn't register the PS service until I stopped windows from "managing my connection". After that I could PING 8.8.8.8 etc successfully.

Comment: Does it at least work for GSM?

Comment: @DanielRobinson This was on Ubuntu, which potentially could be doing something similar since it recognizes it as a cellular modem network device.

Comment: I found out that the IMEI I was using got accidentally tied to two different different SIM cards (ICCIDs) in the Verizon network, probably while I was troubleshooting and trying a second activated SIM card. Could this have been the issue?

Comment: Probably not @CivFan